# Geoprocessing from in-memory layer

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.2

I have a .csv file with 3 fields: lat, long, and value.  I'd like to create a Thiessen Polygon raster from this file in Python without creating intermediate datasets.  Here's what I have:

```
# Create layer from points
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(points_file, 'lon', 'lat', "points_lyr", arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))

# Make polygons
arcpy.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis("points_lyr", "tp", "ALL")

# Rasterize
PolygonToRaster_conversion("points_lyr", "grid_id", "weather_grid")
```

This fails at step 2, raising the following error:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000339: Input points_lyr does not have OIDs
Failed to execute (CreateThiessenPolygons).
```

Is it possible to create Thiessen polygons without first converting "points_lyr" into a shapefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion()` to create a new dataset that will have OIDs, and if you are worried about having to clean up temporary datasets afterwards, **you can do it all in memory**.  Of course if the dataset is ridiculously huge, this could exhaust memory, but most systems will hold reasonably large datasets in memory.

Eg,

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("points_lyr", "in_memory", "pointsFC")
```

After you've finished with the temporary feature class, if your script has much other work to do, you should delete it to free up memory, eg with:

```
arcpy.Delete_management("pointsFC")
```

Although if you're going to explicitly delete the feature class anyhow, then you can just create it as a shapefile (or in a fGDB) instead of in memory.  In memory is substantially quicker for some operations, but you have to weigh that up against how much memory is available/required.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases I usually will pull the "points_lyr" into a new feature class, which will create a new ObjectID field; then run my geo-process.

Yes, it seems silly; but I have found it to work consistently.